# Ругается компилятор на await

Tags: c#

```
private async void play_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (sender is Button)
    {
        //Новая Таска по запуску видео
        cancelTokenSource.Cancel();
        video = VideoFilesP[sender as Button];
        await Task.Run(() =>
       {
           CheckCancel(but_Task[sender as Button]);
       });
        Thread.Sleep(3000);                
        await but_Task[sender as Button].Start();
    }
}
```

При выполнении второй Таски выдает ошибку компиляции:

> Cannot await void

Как исправить?

Comment: А какого типа `but_Task`?

Comment: but_Task.Add(but, new  Task(videoTwoMark, token)); Dictionary с ключом это кнопка на форме

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если `but_Taskp[...]` имеет тип `Task`, то проблема понятна.

`Task.Start` [возвращает `void`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.task.start?view=netframework-4.7.1#System_Threading_Tasks_Task_Start).

Если вы хотите запустить таск, а затем дождаться его, то используйте конструкцию наподобие

```
Task t = but_Task[sender as Button];
t.Start();
await t;
```

---

Я бы отметил несколько проблематичных мест в вашем коде. Во-первых, не стоит использовать `Thread.Sleep` в асинхронном методе, да ещё и бегущем в UI-потоке! Вы же просто вешаете ваше приложение.

Затем, обычно нет смысла держать «холодный», незапущенный таск. лучше складывайте в `but_Task` не `Task`'и, а `Action`'ы, и создавайте таск сразу при запуске. Итого получится:

```
await Task.Delay(3000);
await Task.Run(but_Action[sender as Button]);
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, да void

Comment: А за что минус-то?

Comment: Я вам + поставил, мне очень помог ответ

Comment: @RomanIeromenko: Ну я не вам, а тому, кто поставил таки минус :)

Comment: Странные люди, честное слово

Comment: Действительно странные, здесь есть несколько таких, ходят тролят, и минусы ставят, мне прилетело несколько.

Comment: @VladD ахах , ставлю + тебе и стр. обновляется и нет плюсика

Comment: @DigitalCore: Бывает, глюки :)

Comment: Я человек простой, вижу ответ от @VladD, ставлю плюс :)

Comment: @tym32167: (_покраснел_) Спасибо за доверие, постараюсь оправдать!